# can't login ubuntu 16.04 after change resolution screen with xrandr

Tags: graphics

Help me, i stuck in login screen and just can login with guest mode, but can't with my user , its happen after i add new resolution mode to my ubuntu, with xrandr addmode to 1440x900 pix res, its work and i happy, but when i just try log out, i can't get log in again, please help me, im newbie in ubuntu, and very insterst with this OS, i try every solution in this web, but its all just fail, i keep stuck in login screen, but  so far i try, i can login from tty1 with startx mode, and its seem no problem with Xauthority (i have been trying this over and over again, and its fail), so please halp me, for this problem, thanks..

Comment: can you give screenshoots ? or maybe there is error message that displayed?

Comment: No message error, just cant login user, if i type password and "enter" its blank for a while, and back to login screen,

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution, yet?